# Double facebook sdk import, in my android library project and in target project

Tags: android, facebook, android-library

i've a android library project that use facebook sdk, so i've linked it in my project properties.
The problem is that also the 3rd part Android application that use my library links the facebook sdk.
So the target application link facebbok and my library, and my library links to facebook sdk, finally the facebook sdk is linked twice with conflict obviously.

I check that com/facebook/android goes in my library jar.

How can i solve this double include?

Thanks to all for the support.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, this is what i did. Hope it helps you too.

1. Remove all the libraries in your project.(Properties->javaBuildPath->library(tab)->select dependancy folder->remove)
2. Now go to libs and remove the library.(your project will show some errors, never mind)
3. Finally import the library that contains the sub library.

Comment: Sorry amal but the 3rd part application is not under my control. I must supply only the jar library or an android library project that the 3rd part developer link.

Comment: @amalBit: I don't understand your steps 2 and 3.  Regarding #2, there is no .jar file for my library project.  Regarding #3: What do you mean by "import the library"?  Do you mean using the File -> Import... command?

Comment: go to android build path and remove the v4 dependancy. then go to the lib folder and delete the v4 .jar file from it. At this point your project will show error. Now import the facebook sdk.(this contains the v4 library.) and your project will be error free.